How to order by SUM() DESC when using WITH ROLLUP?
I want to use SELECT WITH ROLLUP in MariaDB to get a summary row in the result set, but also order the remaining rows by SUM() DESC. How to best achieve this?
Using the example from the linked documentation page:
CREATE TABLE booksales ( 
  country VARCHAR(35), genre ENUM('fiction','non-fiction'), year YEAR, sales INT);

INSERT INTO booksales VALUES
  ('Senegal','fiction',2014,12234), ('Senegal','fiction',2015,15647),
  ('Senegal','non-fiction',2014,64980), ('Senegal','non-fiction',2015,78901),
  ('Paraguay','fiction',2014,87970), ('Paraguay','fiction',2015,76940),
  ('Paraguay','non-fiction',2014,8760), ('Paraguay','non-fiction',2015,9030);


SELECT year, SUM(sales) FROM booksales GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP;
+------+------------+
| year | SUM(sales) |
+------+------------+
| 2014 |     173944 |
| 2015 |     180518 |
| NULL |     354462 |
+------+------------+

How do I order the rows by SUM(sales) DESC while still having the summary row at the end?

@Akina for mariadb, yes (adding DESC).  in mysql you would do ORDER BY GROUPING(year), SUM(sales) DESC

@ysth WITH ROLLUP cannot be used with ORDER BY in MariaDB, apparently.

right, you need to wrap it as a subquery and have the order by in the outer query: https://dbfiddle.uk/rkjywQ-2

There may be simpler ways to achieve this, but given that the effect of a rollup is to add an additional summary row with 'NULL' values for the columns specified in the GROUP BY, if you wrap the query in a CTE or derived table, you can reason over the result (after giving the SUM column a name) and then manually manipulate the order by in fashion:
WITH Cte AS
(
    SELECT 
      year,
      SUM(sales) AS TotSales
    FROM
      booksales
    GROUP BY 
      year ASC WITH ROLLUP
)
SELECT * 
FROM Cte
ORDER BY CASE WHEN year IS NOT NULL THEN TotSales * -1 ELSE 0 END ASC;

(In the above I'm assuming the SUM has to be positive - if not you'll need to find another devious way to ensure the NULL year is placed last)
Sql Fiddle Example

no devious ways required, just use multiple ordering conditions order by year is null, sum(sales) desc  though if year is nullable, it gets harder.  in mysql you can order by grouping(year), sum(sales) desc but mariadb has no grouping function.  then you do need to be devious

Yes, you are right
